# How can I solve 403 MediaTypeBlocked Error Django on Docker?

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, debian

When I run this command `docker compose -f local.yml up --build -d --remove-orphans`, I get this error:

```
=> ERROR [some-api_api python-run-stage 2/8] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y    libpq-dev    gettext    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o   6.9s
 => [some-api_postgres internal] load build context                                                                                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 692B                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [some-api_postgres 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/postgres:14.4@sha256:9ceb24f8c5f15c053d973a3610866f473690875dc13eb3282b45302189321040                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [some-api_postgres 2/4] COPY ./docker/local/postgres/maintenance /usr/local/bin/maintenance                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [some-api_postgres 3/4] RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/maintenance/*                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [some-api_postgres 4/4] RUN mv /usr/local/bin/maintenance/* /usr/local/bin     && rmdir /usr/local/bin/maintenance                                                    0.0s
 => [some-api_postgres] exporting to image                                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:ee3ebe58d5d8bac55432307b3994a7dadcf27b8b885e64ffef2ce4307ca02c08                                                                                     0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/some-api_postgres                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => CACHED [some-api_api python-build-stage 1/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y    build-essential    libpq-dev                                0.0s
 => CACHED [some-api_api python-build-stage 2/3] COPY ./requirements .                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => CANCELED [some-api_api python-build-stage 3/3] RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels    -r requirements-dev.txt
```

Then:

```
> [some-api_api python-run-stage 2/8] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y    libpq-dev    gettext    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
#0 1.157 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
#0 1.289 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
#0 1.391 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
#0 2.698 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8184 kB]
#0 3.941 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages [189 kB]
#0 4.029 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [6340 B]
#0 4.764 Fetched 8588 kB in 4s (2203 kB/s)
#0 4.764 Reading package lists...
#0 5.296 Reading package lists...
#0 5.836 Building dependency tree...
#0 5.966 Reading state information...
#0 6.109 libpq-dev is already the newest version (13.8-0+deb11u1).
#0 6.109 Suggested packages:
#0 6.109   gettext-doc autopoint libasprintf-dev libgettextpo-dev
#0 6.139 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#0 6.141   gettext gettext-base
#0 6.369 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
#0 6.369 Need to get 1486 kB of archives.
#0 6.369 After this operation, 6658 kB of additional disk space will be used.
#0 6.369 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gettext-base amd64 0.21-4
#0 6.369   403  MediaTypeBlocked [IP: 199.232.18.132 80]
#0 6.729 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gettext amd64 0.21-4
#0 6.729   403  MediaTypeBlocked [IP: 199.232.18.132 80]
#0 6.742 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gettext/gettext-base_0.21-4_amd64.deb  403  MediaTypeBlocked [IP: 199.232.18.132 80]
#0 6.742 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gettext/gettext_0.21-4_amd64.deb  403  MediaTypeBlocked [IP: 199.232.18.132 80]
#0 6.742 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

and finally:

```
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y    libpq-dev    gettext    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100
```

My Dockerfile and local.yml files:

[local.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1H0B.png)

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVxlz.png)

I couldn't understand cause of the error as I am new to using Docker. Please help me.

Comment: Are you on a corporate network with  very aggressive content blocking?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you, I tried using my mobile internet and it worked.